# Dynamically create Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

Is it possible to dynamically create an Azure Active Directory over the Azure shell or from C#?

The only documentation I was able to find is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest describing some commands but it does not explain how to create a new tenant or Azure AD B2C.

We are builing an application for a lot of client organization. Each organization would need an own active directory and database to seperate them from each other logically and securly. That's why we want to dynamically create active directories. We don't want the client to wait and we don't want to manually create everything for each one.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a Azure Active Directory using Azure Shell or C#. A tenant represents an organization in Azure Active Directory.

Azure AD service instance that an organization receives and owns when it signs up for a Microsoft cloud service such as Azure, Microsoft Intune, or Microsoft 365

Comment: you sure? he talks about Azure AD B2C

Comment: Yes I am, the answer is probably related to B2B. Since the azure ui has the possibility to create multiple azure active directory servers there must be an API for these actions. That is why I hoped that there was a way for me to trigger these actions with code

Comment: I adjusted the description to better explain our usecase